# After call finishInteractiveTransition - black screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to implement transition like iOS 8 mail app swipeable "New email" viewController. This all work fine, except one thing - when "New email" vc (second vc) placed on the bottom of the screen - first viewController is inactive. My code (didn't include `animateTransition:`):

```
- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                                   presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                   sourceController:(UIViewController *)source {
    return self;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed{
    return self;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)interactionControllerForPresentation:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator{
    return  nil;
}

- (id <UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)interactionControllerForDismissal:(id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animator{
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning

- (void)startInteractiveTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    self.transitionContext = transitionContext;
    [self updateInteractiveTransition:0.0];
}

#pragma mark - UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition

- (void)updateInteractiveTransition:(CGFloat)percentComplete{
    NSLog(@"updateInteractiveTransition:%f", percentComplete);

    if (percentComplete < 0) {
        percentComplete = 0;
    }
    else if (percentComplete > 1){
        percentComplete = 1;
    }

    UIViewController *modalVC = [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *nonModalVC = [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    float scaleFactor = 0.9 + 0.1 * percentComplete;
    float alphaVal = 0.5 + 0.5 * percentComplete;
    nonModalVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    nonModalVC.view.alpha = alphaVal;


    CGRect modalVCFrame = modalVC.view.frame;
    modalVCFrame.origin.y = percentComplete * viewH + kModalViewYOffset;
    modalVC.view.frame = modalVCFrame;
}

- (void)cancelInteractiveTransitionWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration{
    NSLog(@"cancelInteractiveTransitionWithDuration");


    UIViewController *modalVC = [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *nonModalVC = [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    CGRect modalVCFrame = modalVC.view.frame;
    modalVCFrame.origin.y = self.cancelUp ? kModalViewYOffset : viewH - kModalViewNavBarHeight;
    NSLog(@"modalVCFrame.origin.y = %f", modalVCFrame.origin.y);
    CGAffineTransform transformVal = self.cancelUp ?
                                                CGAffineTransformMakeScale(kNonModalViewMinScale, kNonModalViewMinScale)
                                                : CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGFloat alphaVal = self.cancelUp ? 0.5 : 1.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        modalVC.view.frame = modalVCFrame;
        nonModalVC.view.transform = transformVal;
        nonModalVC.view.alpha = alphaVal;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self cancelInteractiveTransition];
    }];

    reversed = NO;
}


- (void)finishInteractiveTransitionWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration{

    UIViewController *modalVC = [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *nonModalVC = [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    CGRect modalVCFrame = modalVC.view.frame;
    modalVCFrame.origin.y = viewH ; //+ kModalViewNavBarHeight;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        modalVC.view.frame = modalVCFrame;
        nonModalVC.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        nonModalVC.view.alpha = 1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        [modalVC.view removeFromSuperview];
        [self.transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
        self.transitionContext = nil;

        [self finishInteractiveTransition];

    }];

    reversed = NO;
}
```

If I modify `startInteractiveTransition` method like this

```
- (void)startInteractiveTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
     NSLog(@"startInteractiveTransition");

    self.transitionContext = transitionContext;

    UIViewController *modalVC = [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *nonModalVC = [self.transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
    UIView *containerView = [self.transitionContext containerView];
    [containerView insertSubview:nonModalVC.view belowSubview:modalVC.view];

    [self updateInteractiveTransition:0.0];
}
```

Then first viewController will be active, when second placed on the bottom, but when I close secondVC - appears black screen. The problem is on dismissal we can't add anything to the content view, because the original presenter is still present and will be revealed by the removal of the container view. But how make firstVC response when secondVC on bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. First - do not add to containerView anything while dismissing. Second - make containerView "pass" touches through itself when modalView placed on bottom. For this I added category for UIView and override `hitTest:withEvent:` method